# change the Confirm popup button labels OK and Cancel to "Proceed" and "Return to Page"

Tags: javascript, scripting

I have a requirement to change the Confirm popup button labels OK and Cancel to "Proceed" and "Return to Page". Can someone show me how to do it; i can process when the user clicks on OK=true and Cancel=false; but I want to change the labels OK and Cancel to "Proceed" and "Return to Page". Thanks, Leira

Comment: This is not possible with the built-in `confirm()` function. You'll need to implement an HTML/JavaScript dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what do you mean by:

> I have a requirement

> i can process when the user clicks on OK=true and Cancel=false

If you want to make a custom dialog you can, but the `confirm()` function in javascript doesn't allow for changing the buttons content. Check out [this tutorial with w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp). It will help you achieve your goal (all you have to do is customize it and insert buttons). Here is one of their examples:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```